# std::cout while more text is output underneath

Tags: c++, c++11

I've been working on a project in which the output should  be this:

```
oo
  oo 
    oo
###############
```

So I want the ground (#####...) to output before the 'o', but using std::cout, this doesn't seem to work, because it goes from top to bottom. Is there any method I could use to fix this, or maybe a different outputting method?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?Please come up with the code

Comment: You can use loops as well to get the exact output.

Comment: You want only this pattern to be printed, my question is whether this will be static ?

Comment: @KashifFarazShamsi Yes the (###..) will be static

Comment: It is not easy to implement something like this portably, because `cout` has no concept of screen coordinate. You can have a buffer with the characters and clear the screen (not easy/portable either) after each buffer update. The closest thing would be to use a library to manipulate the screen, for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses . Any answer will be platform dependent unfortunately. Which platform are you in?

Comment: @alfC  wasn't there a ncurses port to Windows that is included with cygwin?

Comment: @Swift, sure there is. https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=ncurses

Comment: `std::cout` does not go from top to bottom. Your typical console window goes from top to bottom.

Comment: P.S.: Typically, if you feel that you need such special output, it's often time to move to a GUI application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So upon further research, it can be done, but it's operating system specific.
The example I found is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h> //This is where you will get the SetConsolePosition and 
Coords struct

int main (void) {

COORD coord;
coord.X = 10;
coord.Y = 1;

std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
std::cout << "World!?" ;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: How come this is operating system specific?

Comment: @Kashif Faraz Shamsi because OSes work differently with console. If for Linux console is only true native mode of output,   for Windows or MacOS that would be GUI.  console there is emulated. But on Linux from under the X server you also might be in emulated console which behaves not quite same as  native one.

Comment: it's better to show that you can store console handle for reuse.. calling getStdHandle  each time probably isn't best method.

Comment: Oh!, I get it now. Thanks @Swift

Answer (score 0):

cout is what it is. It's a standard stream, which works on First In - First Out (FIFO) principle. So text that you print first, will be printed first, then  text will be scrolled up, to provide space for next line.  To output at specified coordinates of screen you  need to change position where next character will be placed.  How to do so, depends on what type of terminal\console you use, including what OS it is (on Linux , there are terminal types that do not support it or do not support it fully).

Check answers here: [Linux drawing in text mode(no gui, desktop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43723558/linux-drawing-in-text-modeno-gui-desktop)

Answer (score -1):

Okay, then you can add the below code in your code before your texts which are printing.

```
cout<<"################\n";
cout<<"oo\n";
cout<<"  oo\n";
cout<<"    oo\n";
```

**Complete code:**

#include 
using namespace std;

```
int main() {
    cout<<"################\n";
    cout<<"oo\n";
    cout<<"  oo\n";
    cout<<"    oo\n";

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: that's not what OP was asking, he needs coordinated method of output in text mode.

Comment: Yes, got it now. My bad. If the code was posted earlier I would have got it.